# Verifying ctypes type precision in Python

Tags: python, c, limit, ansi-c

1. If an API expects a 64 bit type, how can I check that a [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/ctypes.html) type has that many bits if [`sizeof`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.sizeof) returns the number of bytes?
2. How do I know how many bits are in each byte on the current platform?
3. Where is [`CHAR_BIT`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limits.h) defined in Python?

Comment: Nope, an *octet* is 8 bits. Incidentally, most bytes nowadays are an octet wide. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C/C++ function signatures are written with C/C++ types, like "int" or "double" or "uint32_t".  All of these have corresponding ctypes equivalents, so normally you do not care about the number of bits.

That said...

```
import os
print os.sysconf('SC_CHAR_BIT')
```

...is about as close as you will get, I think.  Does not work on non-Unix platforms.  And as tMC points out in the comments, it does not even work on all Unix platforms; I believe it is a GNU extension.

[update]

Actually, the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html) appears to mandate CHAR_BIT == 8.  So on any system that supports the SC_CHAR_BIT sysconf selector, you do not actually need it :-).

Comment: FWIW- on OSX 10.7 on the included Python 2.6; that conf doesn't exist. `os.sysconf('SC_CHAR_BIT')` - `ValueError: unrecognized configuration name`

Comment: Whoopsie.  Looks like it might be a GNU extension...  Thanks.